# I'm looking to make these pictures all be the exact same size and keep the buttons inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, image-scaling, dynamic-columns

Designing a real simple website and I'm trying to get these column heights, button placement, and image sizes perfect. Any suggestions?

https://codepen.io/Smag15/pen/XRQLdB

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <a href="https://localbitcoins.com/?ch=bef7">
                    <div id="buytn" class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://www.forexnewsnow.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Bitcoin.jpg"></img>
                        <div id="buy" class="caption">
                            <h2>Buy Bitcoin</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <a href="https://www.genesis-mining.com/a/18691">
                    <div id="minetn" class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-uK7LaDSSyFE/Vhi2nrCu5iI/AAAAAAAAGE0/2Ht-q9oYO24/s1600/Bitcoin-mining.jpg"></img>
                        <div id="mine" class="caption">
                            <h2>Mine Bitcoin</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <a href="https://localbitcoins.com/?ch=bef7">
                    <div id="spendtn" class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://insidebitcoins.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Shapeshift_article_cover_Bitcoinist.png"></img>
                        <div id="spend" class="caption">
                            <h2>Trade Bitcoin</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.jumbotron {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: #09f;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}

#price{
    background: silver;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I'm not sure how to get the bottoms of the containers to be all on the same line, yet also make sure that the images fill up the same amount of container accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to give image container divs certain height and width and use images as background-image of respective div. That will help you to properly position your image irrespective of their aspect ratio.

This is what I am trying to say, update your thumnail class

```
.thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Then update your html like this

```
<div id="minetn" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-uK7LaDSSyFE/Vhi2nrCu5iI/AAAAAAAAGE0/2Ht-q9oYO24/s1600/Bitcoin-mining.jpg')"></div>
```

And place your buttons below the respective thumbnail divs.

Here is the updated codepen

https://codepen.io/vibhanshu/pen/xdeoqM